# What is value of '_.nextInt' in this expression in Scala

Tags: scala

I am reading the book "Functional Programming In Scala" and I come across this code:

```
trait RNG {
  def nextInt: (Int, RNG)
}

type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)

object Rand {
val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt

def unit[A](a: A): Rand[A] = rng => (a, rng)

// other code...
}
```

I can not understand this line

```
val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt
```

this mean int is a value of type *Rand[Int]* that is set to be *"_.nextInt"* but what is this value?
_ is a wildcard and I can not understand value of this expression.

P/S: Thank you for answer that

```
_.nextInt is (x:A)=>x.nextInt
```

Answer (score 6):

`_.nextInt` is `x => x.nextInt` i.e. a lambda.

Comment: I think you could expand the answer a little. Like explain that `RAND` Is a type alias to a function. So that is why the lambda works and why it is capable of inferring the type of the arguments.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Would you write such answer with more details?

Comment: I would. I didn't, just because I am on the cellphone right now, and is kind of tedious to write with it.

Comment: scala> class A {
     | def method1(): Unit = { println("hello"); }
     | }
defined class A

// this is same as
// f: (A=>Unit) = (x:A) => x.method1
val f : (A=> Unit) = _.method1
f: A => Unit = $$Lambda$1092/0x0000000840673840@25a7fedf

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@1edfedf1

scala> f(a)
hello

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `RNG` is defined as

```
trait RNG {
  def nextInt: (Int, RNG)
}

type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)
```

then `val int: Rand[Int] = _.nextInt` is a shorthand that expands to

```
val int: RNG => (Int, RNG) = (x: RNG) => x.nextInt
```

Comment: Thank you, I edit my question to inlude RNG define;